# Tensorflow Timeline Metadata coming back NaN

Tags: tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow program designed to help me informally benchmark a GPU I am using and, more importantly, understand the profiling tools that come with TensorFlow.  The code does nothing but set up two placeholders for a matrix, and a matmul op, then invokes a session to populate the placeholders and execute the graph ten times.

Here is the code:

```
n = 10240
iter = 10

tf.reset_default_graph()
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        matrix1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n, n], name="Matrix_One")
        matrix2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n, n], name="Matrix_Two")
        product = tf.matmul(matrix1, matrix2, name = "Matrix_Multiply")

date = datetime.now()
cwd = os.getcwd()
LogBase = cwd + "/benchmarks2/"
LogPath = LogBase + date.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + "/"
print(LogPath)

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LogPath, session.graph)
    for i in range(iter):
        m1 = np.random.rand(n, n)
        m2 = np.random.rand(n, n)
        feed_dict = { matrix1 : m1,matrix2 : m2}
        p = session.run( [product], feed_dict=feed_dict, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
        writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%2d' % i)

    tf.summary.FileWriter(LogPath, graph).close()
```

Two peculiarities emerge when I look at the tensorboard graph:

- Note that I run ten iterations, but the tensorboard only shows eight steps, which seems odd
- Most importantly, I never see anything but NaN for the compute time or the memory, as shown below.  Note the Matrix Multiple operation is selected.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Google Web Tracing Framework?  This is the previous way to analyze compute and memory usage timelines.

This isn’t an answer to your question, but it’s a good way to compare and possibly isolate the issue.